# Can debugger be called in a Javascript Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am attempting to use a library I found on [github](https://github.com/brianllamar/slack-typeform-inviter) and unable to debug why the code is not firing.

//slackTypeForm.js

```
   var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    PromiseObject = require('promise-object')(Promise),
    request = require('request'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    Cubby = require('Cubby');

Promise.promisifyAll(request);

var SlackAutoInviter = PromiseObject.create({
    initialize: function ($config) {
        this._typeformUID = $config.typeformUID;
        this._typeformKey = $config.typeformKey;
        this._typeformEmailField = $config.typeformEmailField;
        this._typeformFirstNameField = $config.typeformFirstNameField;
        this._typeformLastNameField = $config.typeformLastNameField;
        this._slackName = $config.slackName;
        this._slackToken = $config.slackToken;
        this._dataFile = $config.dataFile;
        this._cubby = new Cubby({file: this._dataFile});
        this._cubby.set('form-id-since', this._cubby.get('form-id-since') || 1);
    },

    inviteAll: function ($deferred) {
```

// debugger is not hitting here 
        debugger;

```
        var typeFormResponse = _.first(request.getAsync({url: 'https://api.typeform.com/v0/form/' + this._typeformUID + '?key=' + this._typeformKey + '&completed=true&since=' + this._cubby.get('form-id-since') + '&limit=1000', json: true}));

        Promise.map(typeFormResponse.body.responses, this._inviteUser, {concurrency: 5});

        this._cubby.set('form-id-since', Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));

        $deferred.resolve();
    },

    _inviteUser: function ($deferred, form) {
        var inviteResponse = _.first(request.postAsync({
            url: 'https://' + this._slackName + '.slack.com/api/users.admin.invite',
            form: {
                email: form.answers[this._typeformEmailField],
                first_name: form.answers[this._typeformFirstNameField],
                last_name: form.answers[this._typeformLastNameField],
                token: this._slackToken,
                set_active: 'true'
            },
            json: true
        }));

        console.log('[INVITE] ' + form.answers[this._typeformFirstNameField] + ' ' + form.answers[this._typeformLastNameField] + ' <' + form.answers[this._typeformEmailField] + '>');

        $deferred.resolve(inviteResponse.body);
    }
});

module.exports = SlackAutoInviter;
```

// Is there any info out there on how to debug this promise?

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "slack-typeform-inviter",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Chad Scira",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^2.3.10",
    "cubby": "0.0.3",
    "harmony": "0.0.1",
    "lodash": "^2.4.1",
    "promise-object": "^0.1.5",
    "request": "^2.47.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is your function taking a $deferred ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just using `console.log(code);` it works fine.

I haven't got the definitive answer, but my assumption is it has something to do with the promises being delayed, so console.log it is.

***Update and answer**.

The code turned out to be node 0.11.x which uses a different syntax with promises. I have submitted a [pull-request](https://github.com/icodeforlove/slack-typeform-inviter/pull/1) on the module githubg pagewith instructions on how to use nvm to upgrade to the unstable version of node to use this code.

`npm install -g nvm`

`nvm install v0.11.14`

I was then able to debug the code as I pleased.

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to your question?  If not, then you should just use the edit link to edit your question and add this additional information to your question.

Comment: V8 can step into async execution stacks for about half a year and has async stack traces - haven't used them in node yet though.

Comment: I updated the response to include my fix. I all had to do with the syntax being 0.11 syntax